# Swift unbounded memory growth

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a Swift 2.2 app in XCode7.3 using SpriteKit & GameCentre.

My issue is the memory used by the app continues to grow (an additional ~20MB is grabbed every second or so). Eventually this causes the app to crash due to memory issues. I get similar results running on a device (iPhone 6s) & simulator.

I've had a go at running it through Instruments (screenshot below) and this seems to show the issue.

[Instruments screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9QHe.jpg)

From digging into the instruments output, it seems to show a memory leak occurring off a 460 KiB malloc call. I haven't manage to isolate what's causing this from the stack trace.

Instruments output available - not certain how to attach it here. Any suggestions / pointers on where to start?

Comment: With bugs of this size, there is a good bet you are doing something wrong on a fundamental level. Are you using `malloc` in your code? Are you using weak references where you need them?

Comment: Code is all swift2 - so no direct malloc calls being used. If I'm reading the instruments outputs correctly the actual leak is occurring off repeated malloc calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try binary searching your code.  Comment out half your calls.  Still getting a memory leak?  Ok, now you've reduced your search scope by half.  Comment out half of the remainder.  No memory leak?  Great, you've just narrowed down your problem to 1 quarter of your code.  Once you start getting the specific code that is causing the leak, you'll get much more useful answers out of StackOverflow.

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness of the original question - unfortunately I'm basically stuck. I've been going through my code and adding print statements to check when each method call is occurring, I've also been commenting out chunks of code. I've now cut everything back to the bare bare minimum (I'm down to deleting code) and the memory leak has only accelerated (instead of ~20M jumps used memory is now jumping up by ~50M)

Answer (score 0):

Answer has been found - cause is a bug in the Apple/Spritekit code.

As part of setting up the scene I was setting showFields of the SKView to true. Once I disable this (false) the memory leak issue goes away.

From searching for this I found - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27870